# Stop verbose error - A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<)

Tags: asp.net

I am getting a verbose message "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<)" displayed trying to access this URL:
https://My_Web_Server/%3Cscript%3E_q_q=%27%29%28%27%3C/script%3E, which was provided by my Security Team to test site security.

I know why I'm getting an error, but I need to hide the verbose description. I add the entry in the Web.config file below and I get a 500 Internal Server error screen, which is what I want, but the entire site shows that error after adding those lines. I try any other page an it gets the 500 error

```
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to hide anything? You won't see anything except a 500 on remote computers if you use the default settings in web.config. Viewing verbose messages on the server itself is *not* a security risk

Comment: To change what gets displayed, use the [customErrors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx) element in web.config. The default is `RemoteOnly` which means remote computers will see a custom error page or just a 500